# How to reference a leaf from a different root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have this design :

A product has many pricing grids, a grid has many pricing periods

```
Product
 Id
 Name
 Grids[]
  Name
  Periods[]
   Price
   Start
   End
```

Now I have special offers, when a seller create an offer (for instance -10%) he can choose to apply it to a Product or even to a Grid (for instance he doesn't want to apply the offer to the grid "www.apartnerwebsite.com" but he prefers to apply it to the grid "my website").

```
Offer
 OfferId
 OfferName
 ProductIds[]
 GridIds[] //??
```

But I can't do this because there is no grid ids and I can't reference a Leaf from a root aggregate.

Comment: Have you considered making a 'Grid' an aggregate root? Then have both Product & Offer reference the Ids of the grids?

Comment: Isn't it just a workaround ? a grid doesn't exists by itself right ? I have considered it, but it scares me that in a long term I'll have only aggregate roots.

Comment: Well I don't know your full requirements, but designing small aggregates is not a work around. Read these **excellent** articles on the subject (the first one is most relevant): http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011 . If a **Grid** forms part of an **Offer**, as well as a **Product** then it would make sense to me to make it an aggregate of it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Grid is a contender to be its own aggregate root. If a Grid forms part of an Offer, as well as a Product then it would make sense to me to make it an aggregate root. Products & Offers would references their Grid's by ID.

As I mentioned in my comment, you shouldn't fear having a large number of small aggregates. This is actually a positive thing, as Vernon documents in his excellent article: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011

Comment: Thank you I'll have a look at your article. Is there any technique/tools for migrating a leaf to an aggregate root without pain ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. but this is a normal process of "ractoring to a deeper insight" to quote Mr. Evans.

Comment: No worries. It's the best thing I've read on aggregate design.